# SSIS Custom Control UOW (Unit of work) pattern to maintain the transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, transactions

Currently, we are working on SSIS and working on a specific case where we need to implement the unit of work design for our custom created controls. The purpose of UOW (unit of work) is to maintain the transaction at the root level and controlling the sub-transaction done through custom controls. Let me brief you more:

We have created our custom SSIS controls to match our requirements. Out of which, one of the custom control is for Web API. The purpose of this control is to call the existing Web API and get the result in JSON. We want to call multiple Web APIs through the SSIS package and to have shared transactions across all the sequences of API calls. Note that, each Web API has its own transaction handled at the API level. Just to note, SSIS and API both will be hosted on different servers.

Consider the below example to understand the flow in SSIS:

1. Call API-1 (That will do relative operations. Contains its own transaction)
   ↓
2. Call API-2 (That will do relative operations. Contains its own transaction)
   ↓
3. Call API-3 (That will do relative operations. Contains its own transaction)
   ↓
4. Call API-4 (That will do relative operations. Contains its own transaction)

As said, each API call will have its own transaction implemented. Meaning, here four dedicated tasks will have four transactions.

What we want is, if any of the Web API calls fails, we want to roll back the previous API operations. Meaning, if API-1 and API-2 are successfully executed but API-3 fails then roll back the API-1 and API-2 operations. We tried maintaining the transactions at the sequence container level (keeping MSDTC enabled). Meaning,

1. Sequence Container (Transaction = Required, IsolationLevel = Serializable)
   a.  API-1 call
   b.  API-2 call
   c.  API-3 call
   d.  API-4 call

Since we are using our custom control, it is not able to roll back. If we use SQL Tasks instead of custom Web API control, it is doing its job perfectly.

Could anyone suggest any idea/direction/thought on how to maintain distributed/shared transactions over custom controls in SSIS?

Comment: is it just me, or does this sound like a horrible design?